# TypeError: Cannot read property 'expectGET' of undefined for $httpBackend

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, ionic-framework, karma-jasmine

I am getting a few different errors. One of them is the one listed in the title. 
This failure is for my TEST file that is written using Karma.

I'm assuming the problem is related to $httpBackend not registering somewhere. I am building an application using IONIC, Angular, and Rails.

I've tried using both `_$httpBackend_` syntax and the `$httpBackend` syntax in the `beforeEach(inject(function())` and I'm still getting the same error.

Here is the full error:

```
BillService
    ✗ fetches a list of Bills
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module starter due to:
    Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ionic due to:
    Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ionic' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
    http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$injector/nomod?p0=ionic
        at /Users/knowerlittle/Dropbox/Projects/splitter-frontend/www/lib/ionic/js/angular/angular.js:68:12

    TypeError: Cannot read property 'expectGET' of undefined
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/knowerlittle/Dropbox/Projects/splitter-frontend/test/unit/BillService.spec.js:15:16)
```

BELOW IS THE TEST FILE:

```
describe('BillService', function() {
  beforeEach(module('starter'));

  var billService, httpBackend;

  var billData = [{event: "Party"}, {event: "Birthday"}];

  beforeEach(inject(function(_billService_, _$httpBackend_) {
    billService = _billService_;
    httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
  }));

  it('fetches a list of Bills', function(){

    httpBackend.expectGET("http://localhost:3000/bills/").respond(billData);

    var bill1 = { event: "Party"};
    var bill2 = { event: "Birthday"};

    billService.getAll().then(function(bills) {
      expect(bills).toEqual([bill1, bill2]);
    });
    httpBackend.flush();
  });
});
```

Any help would be amazing! Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide a minimal code for your `BillService`. The problem is not due to `$httpBackend` for sure. It's due to something else. And to identify it, I need to have a look at the `BillService`

Comment: Hi @SiddharthAjmera thanks for the response. A bit of a late response but we got it working. It came down to a really silly typo.  `beforeEach(module('starter'))`

Our App was called `splitter` and not `starter` . . . :-).